# Map Spring MongoTempate to repositories during runtime

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Currently I have a repositories package. I map that package to the MongoTemplate like this

```
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myservice.mongodb")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "mycustom.repository" }, mongoTemplateRef = "customMongoTemplate")
public class CustomMongoConfiguration extends MongoConfiguration {

    private String host;
    private String database;
    private int port;

    @Bean(name = "customMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(host,port,database));
    }
}
```

In mongoDbFactory(), I'm using SimpleMongoDbFactory() to return an instance of MongoDbFactory.

Is there a way to make the mapping of my mongoTemplate bean to my repository package during runtime/dynamically?

A small example would be helpful. Thanks